# Magento configurable items - multiple store views and size variations/conventions

Tags: magento, shoes, sizing, configurable-product

I'm running Magento Enterprise 1.11.2.0 and my inventory is primarily shoes. I use 3 store views: EU, UK, and US. My size attribute across these 3 views allows me to specify equivalents for each regional sizing convention.

Some brands have slight variations in only one or two regions.

EXAMPLE: Brand A: UK 7 | US 8 | EU 41.5
                  Brand B: UK 7 | US 8 | EU 41
                  Brand C: UK 4 | US 6 | EU 36.5
                  Brand D: UK 4 | US 6.5 | EU 37.5

If I create an attribute label for each variation then when I am in the store view for a region that does NOT have a variation, the sizes repeat themselves in the layered navigation because Magento sees each attribute label as discrete.

EXAMPLE: A category page with only 1 item from Brand A and 1 item from Brand B viewed in the EU store is fine, but viewing the UK store displays layered nav like so:
                  Size:
                       UK 7 (1)
                       UK 7 (1)
Ideally this would display as:
                  Size:
                       UK 7 (2)

Any help strategizing would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: i did this in the past using jquery, the values are something like UK_6.5, UK_7, EU_39, EU_40, and then dynamically add a dropdown for UK and EU values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up accomplishing this via multiple store views.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting task you have.
There is too much customization to implement your idea.
I can offer you such workaround:
1. Leave only one size attribute.
2. Leave default values from UK store (the one with same values for all brands).
3. On product detail page display some "size guide" which will depend of selected brand.

Comment: The problem with this is that customers searching by size will not see their size in layered nav and we will miss out on the sale.